# Fixed position element inheriting width of flex item

Tags: css, width, css-position, flexbox, fixed

I'm building out a UI that requires a fixed position/sticky element at the bottom of the viewport with a width constrained by a main content area. The main content area is optionally flanked by (sibling) left and/or right sidebars with fixed widths, so I'm using Flexbox to build the three column structure with `flex-grow: 1` on the main content.

I've learned from @Marc Audet's accepted answer at [How can I make a fixed positioned div inherit width of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982966/how-can-i-make-a-fixed-positioned-div-inherit-width-of-parent) that setting `width: inherit` on the fixed element is typically how to solve this problem, but it only seems to work when there's a specified width on its parent, which doesn't help me considering I need the main content area to fill the remaining width of the page.

Does anyone have any ideas for getting around this? Check out my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfc3n6zk/) for the code/example. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Won't calculating the width work for you? `width: calc(100vw - 150px - 250px);`

Comment: @AntonYakushev the point is that the middle section grows automatically if the sidebars are left out, otherwise he could just use `left:150px` and `right:250px` instead.

Comment: @jabram the reason `width:inherit` doesn't work is that the default value for `width` is `auto`, which is being inherited just fine, it's just not helping you in this case. I know possible solutions to your issue but they're highly complex involving multiple sibling selectors...

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I'd love to hear your suggestions if there's a succinct way of getting the concept across!

Comment: 'succinct' is the part I'm worried about  :)  I built a setup exactly like this a while ago (sadly for an internal site so can't share a link) but the CSS was so complex that even my colleagues barely understood it hehe.

Comment: see also https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/18707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45 'Source Code Pro';
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #121;
  color: #FEF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background: blue;
}

.left {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.middle {
  background: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100vw - 400px);
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.middle .fixed-footer {
  background: orange;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  width: inherit;
  padding: 16px 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.right {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 250px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  html {
    margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

Added Star Wars ipsum content to demonstrate `.middle`'s vertical flexibility and how `.fixed-footer` is stationary and is `.middle`'s width.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/je5nchcj/embedded/result/)

Comment: interesting solution, thanks! I'll play around with this a bit, but one negative for me is the the overflow: scroll which will always display a scrollbar on PCs, which I'm trying to get away from.

Comment: If it doesn't have a scrollbar how would you access the content that stretches below the fixed footer? If you use `auto` it jumps the width of the scrollbar thereby making a unsightly offset.

Comment: I'd just rather scroll the page than the element itself. If the left and right sidebars had a lot of content as well, then we'd be dealing with three independently scrolling columns.

Comment: I think I could accommodate that and make the scrollbar appear and disappear without that jumping as well.

Comment: @jabram Check the update, I think I did what I thought wasn't possible.

Comment: This is not a good solution and doesn't answer the question asked "Fixed position element inheriting width of flex item" the proposed solution inherits width from something with fixed width

Comment: @RossJohnson The OP explained: *"...that setting width: inherit on the fixed element is typically how to solve this problem, but it only seems to work when there's a specified width on its parent, which doesn't help me considering I need the main content area to fill the remaining width of the page."* So the OP's real issue is fixed widths to which my solution uses `min-width` thereby imbuing flexibility the OP needs.